# How to speed up the loop over an OpenCV image in Python using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

The goal is to overcome the problem of slow execution of nested loops in python by using the built-in functions in `numpy`.

In the code below, I read an image with `imread` (colors: BGR) into `src` (a numpy array) and I define thresholds for each color (BGR respectively). Then I loop over `src` pixel-by-pixel (with two `for` nested loops), at each iteration I test if the current pixel meets the threshold (three conditions for each value: Blue, Green and Red), in the positive case (the pixel satisfies the conditions) I save its coordinates in a list (line number: `i`, column number: `j`).

```
import cv2

src = cv2.imread('path_to_the_image')   # A numpy array with shape: (width, height, 3) ["3" for BGR]

cond = [10, 20, 30]  # A threshold for each color: Blue, Green and Red respectively

indexes = []  # To save pixel's coordinates which satisfies all three conditions

for i in range(0, src.shape[0]):  # Loop over lines (width)
    for j in range(0, src.shape[1]):  # Loop over columns (height)
        if src[i, j, 0] >= cond[0] and src[i, j, 1] >= cond[1] and src[i, j, 2] >= cond[2]:
            indexes.append((i, j))
```

So, I would like to know how to rewrite this code using `numpy` built-in functions to benefit from its speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3], [10,20,30]],
     [[40,50,60], [10, 30, 20]]
    ])

[*zip(*np.where((a > (10,20,30)).all(-1)))]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 0)]
```

**Note**: `np.where((a > (10,20,30)).all(-1))` alone would give you `[array([1]), array([0])]` which might be better in some cases.